# Fastest way to find if a 'ushort' is present within a Span<ushort> with SIMD?

Tags: c#, performance, .net-core, simd

In C# on .NET Core, I am seeking the fastest method to check whether a given `ushort` value is present within a `Span<ushort>` range. The naive option consists of enumerating the span, but I strongly suspect that a much faster single-core option exists through SIMD (i.e. SSE or AVX).

What is fastest option here? (unsafe code is OK)

Comment: Can you use some other structure, like `Hashset<ushort>`?

Comment: Yes, SSE2 has `pcmpeqw` which lets you check 16 bytes at a time in your linear search.  You can use it the same way a vectorized `memchr` loop is implemented (using `pmovmskb` to get an integer result).  AVX2 has a 32-byte version of the same instruction.  Various possible optimizations include checking a whole cache-line before branching (combining pcmpeq results with an OR).  I don't know C#, but presumably that's a good starting point for manually vectorizing, if your compiler/runtime doesn't autovectorize for you even if you get to an alignment boundary, etc.

Comment: there's a trick to [determine if a word has a byte equal to n](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord), but that probably won't be faster than SIMD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A basic implementation (before applying optimizations such as the ones described by Peter in the comments) might work like this:

```
static unsafe bool ContainsUshort(Span<ushort> data, ushort val)
{
    int vecSize = Vector<ushort>.Count;
    var value = new Vector<ushort>(val);
    int i;
    fixed (ushort* ptr = &data[0])
    {
        int limit = data.Length - vecSize;
        for (i = 0; i <= limit; i += vecSize)
        {
            var d = Unsafe.ReadUnaligned<Vector<ushort>>(ptr + i);
            if (Vector.EqualsAny(d, value))
                return true;
        }
    }
    for (; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] == val)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This requires the `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` package for the unsafe read, without that creating a vector from a span (or array too) is much less efficient. By the way the `EqualsAny` intrinsic is realized with `(v)ptest` instead of `(v)pmovmskb`, `ptest` typically costs more µops so it is comparatively more important to minimize its impact - but since there is no direct access to `ptest` or `pmovmskb` (this limitation can be avoided by using the newer platform-specific `System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86` API) the final "vector to condition" AFAIK still has to be done with `Vector.EqualsAny` (with a vector filled with 0xFFFF) which is a little silly.. nevertheless it was a little faster on my machine (tested such that the return value will be `false`, so the slightly earlier exit of the non-unrolled version didn't come into play)

```
var allSet = new Vector<ushort>(0xFFFF);
int limit = data.Length - vecSize * 2;
for (i = 0; i <= limit; i += vecSize * 2)
{
    var d0 = Unsafe.ReadUnaligned<Vector<ushort>>(ptr + i);
    var d1 = Unsafe.ReadUnaligned<Vector<ushort>>(ptr + i + vecSize);
    var eq = Vector.Equals(d0, value) | Vector.Equals(d1, value);
    if (Vector.EqualsAny(eq, allSet))
        return true;
}
```

Comment: `System.Runtime.Intrinsics.X86` has `pmovmskb`.  e.g. the AVX2 version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.x86.avx2.movemask?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @PeterCordes yes I suppose I should modernize this answer for the modern vector API (which didn't exist in 2018 unfortunately), but it would take effort, so I don't know if I will

Comment: Maybe just add a note that it's out of date, or my comment might be enough.  You might be interested in answering [Find index of unaligned int or long in byte array using SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73178056) ; I didn't find an existing duplicate with C# intrinsics.  Unfortunately the OP has no clue what they're doing with intrinsics so discussing what would be efficient in asm didn't seem to help them.